# Dynamic path for image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple code to implement a dynamic source for a image using JavaScript, but without success.

Coding the image path manually it works and the page shows the image.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "data/3566.JPG";
}
</script>
```

But when using a variable for dynamic path it shows a X instead of the image.

```
<script>
    let ID = 3566;
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "data/ " + ID + ".JPG";
}
</script>
```

I appreciate any help for checking what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You made a typo (voting to close the question). You added an extra space after the `/`.

Comment: NB: Convention reserves variable names that are entirely expressed in CAPITAL LETTERS for **constants**. You should rename your variable to `id`.

Comment: Also, use `encodeURIComponent()` around `id`.  While your ID is URL-safe today, it may not be in the future, so better to get the usage correct now and you won't have to worry about it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u just have space problem

```
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "data/" + ID + ".JPG";
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.